# React: Invalid hook call when importing through 3 layers of Repos

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vite, storybook

In this project I have 3 Repos:

1. AKG-Storybook
2. StoryPage (React/Vite)
3. Test (React/Vite)

In my StoryPage, I am building a common page that is build upon using AKG-Storybook components. I want to package this StoryPage so that it can be imported by future projects. To test that the `StoryPage` works, I performed an `npm link` with the `Test Repo` and imported the page into the `Test Repo`.

Problem:
When StoryPage has a page that imports a component from `AKG-Storybook` that utilizes a hook, the page works fine on the `StoryPage Repo` when I import onto App.tsx and `npm run dev` it. However, when I import that same page in `StoryPage` onto the `Test Repo`, I get an invalid hook call error:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

However, if StoryPage has a page that imports a component from `AKG-Storybook` and it does not utilize a hook, the page will work fine on the `StoryPage Repo` when imported onto App.tsx and `npm run dev` and it will also work fine when I import that same page onto `Test Repo`. The error only appears when the component from `AKG-Storybook` utilizes a hook and is imported into a page in `StoryPage Repo` which is then subsequently imported into the `Test Repo`.

I am unsure what could be the issue but I believe it could be due to more than one copy of React in the same app. Below are the package.json for the Repos:

**AKG-Storybook Package Json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
 },
 "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.13.1",
    "react-dom": ">=16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "cheerio": "=1.0.0-rc.3"
  },
```

**StoryPage Repo Package Json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "akg-ui-storybook": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "akg-ui-storybook": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

**Test Repo Package Json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "akg-ui-storybook": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm link` does weird things, and not recommended for complex situations. The issue is that you're softlinking in another repository, which likely has its own (duplicated) dependencies, which means you have 2 copies of the same library in the tree.

Probably the best built-in way to solve this is to switch to NPM workspaces.